# What Android app is most used for reading music in performance?

Tags: sheet-music, lead-sheets

My band has around 250 tunes frequently played as two tune medleys.  Setlists can be pre-arranged or set up on the fly to compensate for local weather conditions. Kind of like a jazz band, but we're not, we're *really* not.  None of the tunes are available electronically so I'll have to scan them all in, probably in PDF format.

Is there an Android app (preferably free) that would work for me?  I need something that will let me look up tunes and medleys rapidly and an interface with a Bluetooth foot-pedal page turner would definitely be a plus.  I'm also using a 7 inch Android tablet, which may be a deal-breaker.

Comment: You may get better answers to this on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, a new SE site for software recommendations, but be sure to check their help first because they have strict requirements to keep questions fact-based and answerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, a 7 inch Android tablet limits your choices somewhat. I have both a 7 and a 10 inch (hi res) tablet and the bigger size really helps a lot. And iPad has a lot of great apps.

That being said, you should give the [Fakebook](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skrivarna.fakebook.android) app a try. While the Orpheus app recommended above is good, the Fakebook is much more suitable for gigging:
- it loads pages really quick (no parsing delays)
- it reads a lot of different formats, not only PDF
- the search is fast and works great when taking requests
- the easiest and best playlists I have found

Looking at your requirements it seems like a (almost) perfect match; with list features for the medleys, great search and Bluetooth pedal support. It's not free though, but probably the best $2 I have spent on an app.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Orpheus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gramercy.orpheus&hl=en)? I was actually curious about this same thing several months ago when I got my Android phone. Orpheus looks kind of cool from the video. It does support loading PDFs and hands-free page turning, *and* it was designed for 7-10" tablets, which were three of your requirements. Apparently at least one reviewer complained about PDFs loading slowly, but you can never be certain if a performance complaint is due to the app or that particular user just having a slow phone because it's bloated with apps. I'd give it a try if you haven't already.

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it.  Give a spin and tell me how you like it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not making this the official answer because it varies so much from the OP, but the solution I finally came up with was this:

- Buy a 10 inch tablet
- Scan each two-tune medley into a single-page PDF document
- Name all the PDFs with the name convention `FirstTune-SecondTune.pdf`
- Put all the tunes into a single folder and then just use the PDF file load dialog to load up the tune I want.